# Content disappears when ng-controller is added

Tags: angularjs, controller, search-form

I have a list of fruit, and am able to use the searchFor filter to display the item I've searched for. I'd like to click a button, and send that item to a separate div on the page, using a controller. However, whenever I add ng-controller to the page (I think it's supposed to go in the body tag), my list of fruits completely disappears. Help! I've been racking my brain all day, and nothing seems to be working!!

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"

<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app ="">
<div ng-init="items = [
{type: 'strawberry', name: 'Herbert Strawberry', occupation:         'dogwalker', superpower: 'power-C boost', imageurl: 'images/strawb.jpg' },

{type: 'blueberry', name: 'Ulysses Blueberry', occupation: 'construction worker', superpower: 'super strength', imageurl: 'images/blueb.jpg' },

{type: 'orange', name: 'Otto Sly Orange', occupation: 'ninja', superpower: 'serious defense', imageurl: 'images/orange.jpg' },


]"> 
</div>

<h2>Summon your Vitamin Power</h2>
<p>Which of these did you eat today?</p>
<form name="add_item_form" novalidate ng-submit="additem()">
<input type="text" placeholder="what'd you eat?" ng-model="searchFor"     ng-required="true"/>

<button ng-click="additem(new_item)" ng-disabled="add_item_form.$invalid" class="btn btn-success">Add to Your Arsenal</button>

<ul class = "item group" ng-repeat= "item in items | filter:searchFor">
<div class="adding_item">
<li ng-model="adding_item.type">
{{ item.type }}
</li>
<li ng-model="adding_item.name">
{{ item.name }}
</li>
<li ng-model="adding_item.occupation" >
{{ item.occupation }}
</li>
<li ng-model="adding_item.superpower">
{{ item.superpower }}
</li>
<li ng-model="adding_item.imageurl">
  <img ng-src ="{{ item.imageurl }}" alt="{{ item.type }}">
</li>
</div>
</ul>

</form>


<div class="arsenal">
<h2>Nutrition arsenal</h2>
{{ item.type }}
{{ item.name }}
{{ item.occupation }}
{{ item.superpower }}
{{ item.imageurl }}
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function itemListController( $scope ){

    $scope.items = [
    {type: 'strawberry', name: 'herbert', occupation: 'dogwalker
    ', superpower: 'power-c boost', imageurl: 'images/strawb.jpg' },
    {type: 'blueberry', name: 'Ulysses', occupation: 'construction worker', superpower: 'super strength', imageurl: 'images/blueb.jpg' },

{type: 'orange', title: 'otto sly', occupation: 'ninja', description: 'serious defense', imageurl: 'images/orange.jpg' }

    ];

    $scope.additem = function( new_item ){
        $scope.items.push( new_item );
        $scope.adding_item = {};
    };

};
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a console error? You're adding `ng-controller = 'itemListController'` to the body tag?

Comment: Can you post more of your code, including the controller code and which DOM element you tried to apply it to?

Comment: The HTML above is malformed - angular does not behave well when HTML is malformed (unclosed tags, missing tags, etc). It will do unpredictable bad things.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have all the code on html page, the page will become malformed and content will never get render on the page. You should separate out the things like you JavaScript code should be placed in different JS file and then will provide reference of that script file on the page.

Also you had not declared angular module, while Angular 1.3 + required `angular.module` should be defined before using it in `ng-app` directive.

angular.module('app',[]) will be applied on the page as `ng-app="app"`

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="itemListController">
  <h2>Summon your Vitamin Power</h2>
  <p>Which of these did you eat today?</p>
  <form name="add_item_form" novalidate ng-submit="additem()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="what'd you eat?" ng-model="searchFor" ng-required="true" />
    <button ng-click="additem(new_item)" ng-disabled="add_item_form.$invalid" class="btn btn-success">Add to Your Arsenal</button>

    <ul class="item group" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchFor">
      <div class="adding_item">
        <li ng-model="adding_item.type">
          {{ item.type }}
        </li>
        <li ng-model="adding_item.name">
          {{ item.name }}
        </li>
        <li ng-model="adding_item.occupation">
          {{ item.occupation }}
        </li>
        <li ng-model="adding_item.superpower">
          {{ item.superpower }}
        </li>
        <li ng-model="adding_item.imageurl">
          <img ng-src="{{ item.imageurl }}" alt="{{ item.type }}">
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </form>

  <div class="arsenal">
    <h2>Nutrition arsenal</h2>
    {{ item.type }} {{ item.name }} {{ item.occupation }} 
    {{ item.superpower }} {{ item.imageurl }}
  </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('itemListController', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [{
    type: 'strawberry',
    name: 'herbert',
    occupation: 'dogwalker',
    superpower: 'power-c boost',
    imageurl: 'images/strawb.jpg'
  }, {
    type: 'blueberry',
    name: 'Ulysses',
    occupation: 'construction worker',
    superpower: 'super strength',
    imageurl: 'images/blueb.jpg'
  }, {
    type: 'orange',
    title: 'otto sly',
    occupation: 'ninja',
    description: 'serious defense',
    imageurl: 'images/orange.jpg'
  }];

  $scope.additem = function(new_item) {
    $scope.items.push(new_item);
    $scope.adding_item = {};
  };
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/p13xQ8hYhTL39id5F4Vl?p=preview)